# Android - Change only the alpha TextView's text

Tags: android, colors, textview, alpha

Say I have this code:

```
int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
```

How would I change only the Alpha on this color?

For Example:

if color is `0x00ffffff`, how would I change it to `0xffffffff` ?

Is there a method for that or I need to do some hex/int manipulations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, the straight answer to your question of *"if color is 0x00ffffff, how would I change it to 0xffffffff ?"* to simply to use compound bitwise or:
`color |= 0xff000000;`.

But I reckon maybe some co-workers would rather you didn't do this kind of thing on the java-side of Android development: you have a wonderful helper class called `graphics.Color` [provided by Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)! It does just the same things underneath, but'll really help your code readibility, especially considering that an `int` type color in android isn't necessarily a hex color value but could also point to an artbirary id of a resource in the `color` xml. Argh.

An eg would be:

```
int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
int newColor = Color.argb(yourNewAlphaVal, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color))
```

Not fast, but I'm guessing you don't need it to be.

Of course, this is a personal opinion about what to use here, and I hope this helps!

Comment: I already looked in `graphics.Color`. There is no method to set Alpha. Only to get Alpha.

Comment: Added API level 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int, int, int, int)

Comment: Really hope this helps. The reason why you can't *set* a color value is that it's an `int`. `int`s can't be set in java- you have to create a new one. That's why the helper is just a load of statics.

Comment: Sorry scrap "create". That was awful explaining. You don't "create" ints. What I meant is that `int`s are primitive data type in java, so when using an `int` to represent a complex concept, like color, you dont APIs that modify by reference, because, of course, ints can't be set, and that's why there is "no method to set Alpha" as you rightly say. For that, you'd need a Color object wrapping an int, and that just happens to not be the way we've gone.

Comment: Oh, I missed the Color.[color](color) method. That is what I need. Thanks.